How to create smooth interpolations between two images with OpenCV?
I have been trying to create smooth interpolated images between two images (they might be a bit rotated, translated and/or zoomed) and came up with this function
def interpolate_images(image1, image2, n_interpolations):
    # Convert to grayscale for feature detection
    gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect ORB keypoints and descriptors
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray1, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray2, None)

    # Match features using brute-force matcher
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

    # Extract location of good matches
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    # Find homography matrix
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(dst_pts, src_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

    # Identity matrix for the first image
    identity_matrix = np.eye(3)

    h, w = image1.shape[:2]

    # Interpolation between identity matrix and homography
    interpolated_images = []
    for i in range(n_interpolations + 1):
        alpha = i / n_interpolations
        # Interpolated transformation matrix
        interpolated_matrix = (1 - alpha) * identity_matrix + alpha * M

        # Warp the first image with the interpolated matrix
        warped_image1 = cv2.warpPerspective(image1, interpolated_matrix, (w, h))

        interpolated_images.append(warped_image1)

    return interpolated_images

However, when I run it with two very similar images like


and with the code
img1 = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")

# Interpolate frames
n = 4
interpolated_frames = interpolate_images(img1, img2, n)

for index, image in enumerate(interpolated_frames):
    cv2.imwrite(f"interp_{index}.jpg", image)

cv2.imwrite(f"interp_{n+1}.jpg", img2)

there is still a rough cut between the last interpolated image (interp_4.jpg) and the actual second image (image2.jpg=interp_6.jpg).
How can this be fixed, so I get a smooth transition interpolation between the two images image1 and image2?
Ideally the interpolated images only show a combination of rotation, translation and zooming between the images image1 and image2 ...
Does not have to be OpenCV, a different library can do as well ...

you stopped at the wrong tutorial. look at the next one. your code is missing an important step in a successful feature match and homography estimation.

and what is missing...?

that would be Lowe's ratio test.

I would really appreciate if you could create a complete and working answer, in order to me to understand what you are trying to tell me, to explore this possible solution, and to accept your solution when it is working...

Researching is asking. I am asking here, stackoverflow is a platform for asking specific questions! If you cannot help with that question - then simply don't!

I ran your code with my adjusted version of stitching and without, I don't really see any differences. What are your expected results? I might not be able to help you with the interpolation, but I can maybe help you with the stitching... @Alex

What I want to have are intermediate images that transition smoothly from image1 to image2. So the first image is image1. The second image is almost image1, but slightly rotated, moved, zoomed to start matching image2. The third image is again rotated a bit more, moved a bit more etc. to match image2 even better and so on

assuming the homography is correct (you should check by overlaying one picture warped onto the other picture without warp), then plain linear interpolation on the homography might not cause a linear motion. an elementwise linear interpolation can cause an implausible matrix, with a weird scaling/rotation/shear component.

you might have to project one picture's corners into the other, and then interpolate those points, and generate a homography from that (getPerspectiveTransform).

and how to do that in python? I am not an expert in image transformations. That is why I am asking a question here. Also, I am not interested in the "corners" of the images, I want to match the visible features, which are visible in BOTH images, between image1 and image2 (see the images for better understanding)...
